# check a checkbox inside the gridview on row select

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this code that checks the checkbox on row click but the problem is i cant click on the checkbox itself.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
               //$("#<%=grdRP.ClientID %> td").click(function () {
               $('body').on('click', 'tr.dataRow', function () {
                   selectRow($(this).closest("tr"));
               });
           });

           function selectRow(row) {
               var firstInput = row[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
               firstInput.checked = !firstInput.checked;
           }
```

here's the html code for the gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdLocation" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Width="420px" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No records Found" OnRowDataBound="grdLocation_RowDataBound" >
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

                                    <Columns>
                                          <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkLocSelected" runat="server"/>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Location Num" HeaderText="Location Num" SortExpression="Location Num" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Location Name" HeaderText="Location Name" SortExpression="Location Name" />
                                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Loc Group" HeaderText="Loc Group" SortExpression="Loc Group" />

                                    </Columns>
                                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
                                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#90FF90" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black"  />
                                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
                                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
                                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
                                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
                                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Put some log or add break points. Where is your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the checkbox you fire two `change` events. Which basically means it checks and unchecks instantly and you don't see any change. To prevent this make sure your function doesn't fire when you click on the checkbox.

You can match your element against `event.target`.
In this case i'm assuming matching `tagName` would be enough

```
$('body').on('click', 'tr.dataRow', function (e) {
    if(e.target.tagName != 'INPUT') {
        selectRow($(this).closest("tr"));
    }
});
```

Alternatively you can try `event.preventDefault()`

```
$('.dataRow input').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am alittle bit confused about what you're trying to accomplish. So, on clicking on the row you want to select the row and select the check box, but also want to be able to select/deselect the checkbox?

Comment: My problem is when I try to click on the checkbox I cant seem to click it, but when i click the gridview row it will be checked. What I want is to be able to click on both checkbox and the gridview row not only on the gridview row.

Comment: We have actually the same problem, What I understand, the gridview has a row click event using rowdata command event, when the user clicked the a specific row, the checkbox on the row will be checked. However, When the checkbox itself it to be clicked, the checkbox is not checked, maybe because of the existing javascript code for the gridview row click event